# Is it possible to use short ints (16-bit) in PHP?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

Background: I have a large 2D array of integers that I need to load into memory in PHP for each Apache request. I want it to take up less memory.

PHP stores ints in `PHP_INT_SIZE` bytes, which is 32 bits on most systems. All the integers are less than 2^16, which means they could be a [short int](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer) (eg in C). Am I right in thinking that storing ints as short would take up half the RAM?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do:

```
$s = (short) 1234; // takes up 2 bytes instead of 4
```

More info:

- The array takes up about 100mb of RAM and is generated by including a 30MB [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) dump
- The array is written in a cron process. Only the reading needs to be memory efficient (and quick)
- The only operations I need to do on the integers are comparing all of them (<, >, ===) and then reading a few of them (similar to the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm))
- Reading each value from a DB is way too slow as there are a few hundred million reads per request

Some crazy ideas:

- Use [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) / [unpack()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) but that would still store the values as 32 bit ints when they were unpacked
- Store the values as pixels in an image and use PHP's [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to read them (would this be slow)
- Use [shmop_read()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-read.php) and have the Apache processes share the array
- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) might work but I have no experience with it and I guess it would be many times slower than a native PHP array
- Learn C++ and write a PHP extension
- Recompile PHP (or [HipHop](http://wiki.github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/)?) to use 2 bytes for ints
- Use [Igbinary](http://opensource.dynamoid.com/) (useful, but will have same problem as pack())

Comment: definitely use the shmop_* functions... other than that I can only think of the same thing BarsMonster comes up with.

Comment: Are you sure you couldn't use mysql and memory tables? Perhaps you could even write the comparisons in query form to avoid sending data back & forth with php

Comment: serialize and unserialize are faster than var_export, btw

Comment: @Michael, a MySQL may be possible. I'll have to look into it.
 

@Raveren, serialize is faster than var_export, but is unserialize(file_get_contents()) faster than require()? unserialize seems to use more memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend last approach. :-)

For the quick solution, I would pack 2 your integers in 1 PHP integer using this:

```
$big = $int1 + ($int2<<16);

And uppack as:

$int1 = $big & 65535;
$int2 = ($big>>16) & 65535;
```

Also, BIG thumbs up for using shared memory. This will make your APP way faster.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. The integers need to be accessed randomly so there could be some CPU overhead with this, but if it works then the memory savings should be worth it. I'll give it a go...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a task PHP has been designed for.

I recommend you write an application that has the data in-memory and does the calculations with it and then interface with it in PHP to get the results.

PHP's integer size is actually 64-bit on most 64-bit Unix-like platforms.

The shared memory is not a very good option because you still have to copy the data to PHP's memory space.

Writing an extension that keeps everything in memory and accesses it directly is possible but not very practical since you'd have to use shared memory (or some other IPC mechanism) anyway, because you typically run several PHP processes.

Comment: I'd like to write something that interfaces with PHP, but I wouldn't know where to start. Any pointers?

Comment: You could use sockets or some form of [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing). For Java, you can use the [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks. Only a portion of the array would need to be in PHP's memory space at a time, so I think shmop functions *may* work. Sharing the memory would be the ideal solution as this would scale much better.

Answer (score 1):

i'd generate and store the array in a binary packed format and extract numbers only when you need them

```
function elem($n) {
    global $buf;
    return (ord($buf[$n << 1]) << 8) | ord($buf[$n << 1 | 1]);
}

$buf = file_get_contents(binary file generated by cron);
if(elem(2) > elem(10)).....
```

you can make it fancier by writing a class that implements ArrayAccess, so that you can simply use myPackedArray[x] instead of elem(x) in the rest of code.